# JPA - updating an embedded entity generates invalid SQL

Tags: sql, entity, updating

I am trying to update an embedded entity and JPA seems to generate the wrong SQL.

I have a Company entity with an embedded Logo entity

```
@Entity
public class Company {

  private Long id;
  @Embedded
  private Logo logo;

  // Omitted other fields, getters, setters, etc

}

@Embeddable
public class Logo {

  private String fileName;
  private String fileExtension;
  private String imageDataType;

  // Omitted getters and setters
}
```

In my DAO method I am trying to update the embedded logo like this:

```
@Override
public void setLogo(Logo logo, Long companyId) {
    String q = "update Company c SET c.logo = :logo where c.id = :companyId";
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(q);
    query.setParameter("companyId", companyId);
    query.setParameter("logo", logo);
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

JPA (Hibernate actually) generates the following SQL.

```
update px_company set file_extension, file_name, file_type=(?, ?, ?) where id=?
```

Hibernate seems to understand it must update the three embedded logo fields, but it generates invalid SQL for it. The generated SQL results in an error.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' file_name, file_type=('jpg', '7679075394', 0) where id=1' at line 1
```

Any idea how I should update the embedded entity?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A bit old but just had the same issue - you should fully resolve properties of embedded classes in JPQL:

```
update Company c
SET c.logo.fileName = :fileName
    ,c.logo.fileExtension = :fileExtension
    ,c.logo.imageDataType= :imageDataType
where c.id = :companyId
```